# MY SQL getdate - yesterday to 7 days ago

Tags: mysql

I have a db with value that I convert to date

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo_date,'1971/12/31'),106) AS Date
```

and I am trying to have 7 days without today. I am ok to get last 7 days with today by using below code

```
SELECT datediff(day,'DEC 31 1971',getdate())-7
```

but I can not get rolling last week ie yesterday (Thursday) to - 8 (Wendsday)?

Comment: I am very confused about what you are asking for. Can you please try to explain in an additional way?

Comment: Your query seems have syntax of MS SQL Server, not mysql. Is there any mistake about db type ?

Comment: You are spot on, it is MS SQL Server.

Comment: What I am trying to have is rather simple. As oppose to of the last 7 days ,today Wend to last Thu, I am trying to have yesterday Tue to last Wend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brain fart! Found the solution in rather easy way.

```
wo_date > (SELECT datediff(day,'JAN 01 1972',getdate())-7) 
AND wo_date <= (SELECT datediff(day,'JAN 01 1972',getdate()))
```

Thanks again for inspirations!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE()-9,GETDATE() -1)

--verify
SELECT GETDATE()-9  --2018-01-24    LAST WEDNESDAY
SELECT GETDATE()-1  --2018-02-01    YESTERDAY
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I reckon because my dates needs to be converted it is not working. When I verify it gives "Operand type clash INT is incompatible with DATETIME". I use the following to convert `CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo,'1971/12/31'),106) AS WoDate`